# LTE NR split throughput among different bands and carrier

Tags: bandwidth, lte, 5g

Using a mobile device I can measure the throughput in download and upload while connected to an LTE and/or NR mobile cell.
If I know the details of the cells to which the device is connected and so I know for example the bands that they are using, the carrier etc, is it possible in some way to split the final throughput among the different involved carriers to know for example that x% of the throughput went through the 2nd carrier of the band 3 while y% went through the 1st carrier of band 7 etc?

Comment: No. Different carriers will assign you different IP addresses so the other end of the connection will think your endpoint is multiple, different devices.

Comment: mmm I'm afraid my question wasn't clear. The carriers I'm talking about work at the physical layer so they are not involved in assigning IP addresses

Comment: and for carrier I mean the one that is used in RF modulation